# Magento CE - MultiStore

Tags: multistore, magento-ce

My question is maybe quite simple to answer: `We are about to deploy Magento CE on a server` that will be `dedicated to gather the companies located` in Panama Zona Libre de Colon. There are approximately 2000 companies. What we want to accomplish is a site like Amazon, but where the companies will be in charge to list their own products under the supervision of my company, meaning that they will need access to upload product details and pictures to their own "store", we will get paid using our payments gateway and once a week we are paying the suppliers after charging our fees.

Would it be possible something like that? is so, could somebody point me in the right direction?

This is what I have done already www dot zonalibredecolon247 dot com it's an unfinished example site for our customers

Comment: Instead of use mutistore .use good marketplace extension....is better idea

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend EE,

afaik CE doesn't support different merchants in Backend. So every merchant can see all products.

Also performance could be an aspect that speaks for EE. Many optimisations are not available for CE yet.

Comment: EE sucks, use marketplace extension.